# How to hide Parse.com URL properly in activation email?

Tags: html, parse-platform, email-verification

I have integrated Parse.com to my app, so that I managed to signup and login with my app to the Parse.com backend.

I also enabled Settings --> Email --> Email Settings --> **Verify user emails**

New users will receive an email with an activation link like:
https://www.parse.com/apps/testemaillogin/verify_email?token=C6MDk6PBgegdfgH1boMPj&username=name%40email.com

Parse.com provides to hide Parse.com URLs:

> By uploading attached file to your server and entering its address
>   below, you can hide parse.com from your users. This page is an iframe
>   for Parse that lets your domain be the front-end to our back-end.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- This page is a passthrough frame used to host a parse.com experience from your server.
     If you choose to use this feature, be sure to tell Parse where you put this page in your
     app settings page.
     In general, there should be no reason to edit the contents of this page -->
<head>
  <style type='text/css'>
    html {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .chromeless {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      border: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    .scrollable {
      overflow: auto;
    }
    .noscroll {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    h1, p {
      padding: 15px;
      color: #0067AB;
      font: inherit;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
  </style>
  <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'><!--

    window.onload = function() {
      // When there are query strings, this page is being used to pass content onto parse. Create
      // the iframe to do so. Forwards relevant query parameters onto the iFrame.
      if (window.location.search) {
        var urlParams = {};
        (function () {
            var pair, // Really a match. Index 0 is the full match; 1 & 2 are the key & val.
                tokenize = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
                // decodeURIComponents escapes everything but will leave +s that should be ' '
                re_space = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\+/g, " ")); },
                // Substring to cut off the leading '?'
                querystring = window.location.search.substring(1);

            while (pair = tokenize.exec(querystring))
               urlParams[re_space(pair[1])] = re_space(pair[2]);
        })();

        var base = 'https://www.parse.com';
        var link = '';
        var query = '';
        for (param in urlParams) {
          if (param == 'link') {
            link = urlParams['link'];
          } else {
            if (query != '') {
              query += "&";
            }
            query += param + '=' + encodeURIComponent(urlParams[param]);
          }
        }

        // Ensure there's a leading slash to avoid open redirect
        if (link.charAt(0) !== "/") {
          link = "/" + link;
        }

        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.setAttribute('src', base + link + '?' + query);
        iframe.setAttribute('class', 'chromeless scrollable');
        document.getElementById('content').appendChild(iframe);

      // Otherwise, this page is likely being viewed by the app owner. Explain how to use it.
      } else {
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 
          '<h1>This page lets you host Parse.com content from your own domain.</h1>' +
          '<p>Right click <a href="' + encodeURI(window.location.pathname) + '">here</a> to save this page. ' +
          'Upload it to your own website and paste the URL in the "Parse Frame URL" ' +
          'app settings at Parse.com.</p>';
      }
    }
    //-->
  </script>
</head>
<body class='chromeless noscroll'>
  <noscript>We apologize, but user management requires javascript</noscript>
  <div id='content' class='chromeless noscroll'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I renamed that file to *parse.html* and uploaded it to **http://my.space.com/parse.html**

Then I entered under 
Parse.com --> Settings --> Email --> Hide Parse.com URL --> Parse Frame URL
the above mentioned phrase:
http://my.space.com/parse.html

Now, the activation link in my email is like:

> http://my.space.com/parse.html?link=%2Fapps%2testemaillogin%2Fverify_email&token=BPkcfIrEfvcnbj6uDnFsdfpWI&username=name%40email.com

as you can see to the previous version,

> https://www.parse.com/apps/testemaillogin/verify_email?token=C6MDk6PdedgdfgH1boMPj&username=name%40email.com

the `/` in the URL were replaced by `%2F` (as in between testemaillogin and verify_email)

When I click on the new activation link, nothing happens --> My Parse.com backend still tells me for the **emailVerfication** field **false**

**What did I make wrong?**

EDIT, just for completeness: When I enter just the server to that settings field
http://my.space.com?link=%2Fapps%2Ftestemaillogin%2Fverify_email&token=wyFHdG4iQeqAcJ8I3to4UbPII&username=name%40email.com

I get:

> 403 Forbidden
>       Code: AccessDenied
>       Message: Access Denied
>       RequestId: 775E40B2F6002281
>       HostId: t34pG3CX5JBDRjnm0MfvlU7J7Ox9pOCYNTf44oTw3JMbolYOMZ2c7r2yyuyRzH0S3Cxvc=
>   An Error Occurred While Attempting to Retrieve a Custom Error Document
>       Code: AccessDenied
>       Message: Access Denied